# Link to external site to jump to the search result without query in the URL

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm trying to link my site to an external site where they have a search function. I already have my query from my site and want to pass it to them so I could jump to the search results straightaway. However, upon looking at their site they don't put the query in the URL.

The site is this one https://www.mitomap.org/foswiki/bin/view////Main/SearchAllele. As you can see when you do the search from the input box, it doesn't update the URL.

I'm not sure if this is do-able. Is there anything I could do to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You don't see any query in the URL because the search data is sent via POST-Request.

The sent parameters are:

```
validation_key: SOME_RANDOM_STRING
starting: 12
ending: 12
```

Since the site uses a validation_key which is probably some kind of protection against CSRF. So my suggestion is to not try to implement this POST-Request since it will cause you headaches.